Is it safe to use "conflicted" instead of fully qualifying namespaces for package development in R?
The usual advice, when developing R packages, is to always fully qualify package dependencies, rather than importing the namespace.
https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-mindset-background.html#sec-dependencies-namespace-motivation
The above link spells out the rationale for this, but to summarise:

if 2 packages expose 2 different functions with the same name, then there is an ambiguity about which one to use.
Additionally, if the user of a package creates their own function with a colliding name, then the package itself will try to use it, instead of the correct intended function.

However, there is a special package called conflicted which helps to manage these sorts of problems. I always use conflicted for any specific analytical work I am doing. However, can I safely import dependencies inside packages I develop, by using "conflicted"? Do I still have to do lib::func()?

Its a convenience for you at a (possibly minor cost) to the package users as its an extra dependency. So its probably more a question of who your package users are; if they are your colleagues then its more of a goer, if its the R community as a whole, you'd be less inclined to do it. That's how it seems to me at first glance. Theres also the question of your own needs, saving on typing vs ease of seeing at a glance for any function you use that has a name conflict which source is being used, but only you can answer that and it seems you are leaning to saving typing.

In addition to what @NirGraham mentions, you will probably need to fully qualify package names (or use @importFrom or similar) if you are planning to submit your package on CRAN.  My answer here may be helpful.

Thank you @NirGraham and Limey. You have good points about why to prefer the usual convention. But I don't think these answer  the question about if it is safe to just use "conflicted". I suppose I could try to set up an experiment but not sure if I trust myself to fully understand the scenarios that need to be tested.

you can see by looking at the reverse imports on CRAN what packages use conflicted. there are a few (though not many)
